# Can't find storyboards using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

## Hey you all.

```js
var $storyboards; // This is the wrapper were all stroy boards are.
// Listen to URL changes when clicking the back or forward buttons in the browser.
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  LoadPage(document.location.pathname, !history.state || stateCount > history.state.stateCount);

};

var stateCount = 0;
$( document).ready(function() { 
    $storyboards = $('#storyboards');
    $('.storyboard').attr('data-url', location.pathname);

  
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').addClass('splash-screen-hidden');
    }, 3000);
  
   $(document).on('mouseover mouseout','#menu a', function(e){
     
    $('#menu a').not(this).toggleClass('toggle');
     
   }).on('click', '#menu a', function(e){ 
     if(e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) return;
     // Listen to the click event on the a tags in the menu 
     
     // Prevent the default behavior so the browser doesn't load the page.
     e.preventDefault();
     
     var $this = $(this);
     var url = $this.attr('href');
     var title = $this.attr('title');
    
    NavigateToPage(url, title);
      
   })
});

function LoadPage(url, back){
  
  
  var $all_storyboard = $('.storyboard'); // This is all the storyboards we have in the page. 
  
  var $storyboard = $all_storyboard.filter('[data-url="' + url + '"]');
  var storyboard_exists = $storyboard.length > 0;
  
  PreparePageForLoad();
  
  if(storyboard_exists)
    StoryboardIsLoaded($storyboard.hide());
  else {
    console.log("we do not have the storyboard.. go load it!");
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
        $storyboard = $('.storyboard', data);
        $storyboard.attr('data-url', url);
        $storyboards.append($storyboard);
        StoryboardIsLoaded($storyboard.hide());
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Oops! We could not load this page!.');
        GoToRoot();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I really have a huge problem since I have to deliver my website project tomorrow morning and right now it's not working very well.

The real problem is I'm having trouble with loading between my pages. I'm using storyboard and ajax to switch out the code/content in the HTML without making a page load. So I get these sweet smooth transition between my pages.

I tested it on my own server and domain and it all works fine, but because I have to deliver the project/folder on another server the shit won't work. The main reason is that I have to put it all in a folder on the server and it's messing up the root navigation.

When I click on the link it goes: http://websitename.com/html-document/ 
But it should be: http://websitename/myfolder/html-document/

So the problem is it's going out of my folder and looking for the HTML document outside my folder instead of looking at it.

Here is the link to the website: http://franklyone.com/sylvester-svend/

Thanks in advance - Love

Comment: Can you not just change the `url` parameter passed in to `LoadPage()`? If not, it sounds like an `.htaccess` issue.

Comment: Mhhh maybe like this? - function LoadPage( '/foldername', url, back)

Comment: Not quite; that would add a third function parameter rather than overwriting the existing one. Now that you've added the second part of your code, you could change `document.location.pathname` in the call.

Comment: Don't quite follow to be honest - you mean that i should change the `document.location.pathname` to `/foldername` ???

Comment: Try replacing it with `window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')`.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work...